# Filter products available in pos in odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

The pos module extends `product.template` and adds `available_in_pos` field. In a select field to choose a product, I would like to filter only products available in pos.

I tried the domain `[('product_tmpl_id.available_in_pos', '=', True)]` but I get this error

`Unknown field "product.template.available_in_pos" in domain of <field name="product_id"> ([('product_tmpl_id.available_in_pos', '=', True)]))`

Anyone knows how I achieve this?

Comment: `('product_template_id.available_in_pos', '=', True)` try this

Comment: Doesn't work: `Unknown field "product.product.product_template_id"` which makes sense since the name of related field is `product_tmpl_id`

Comment: `point_of_sale` is installed but apparently it must also be added as a dependency in the manifest file. Was able to make it work, Thanks anyways

Comment: `('product_id.product_tmpl_id.available_in_pos', '=', True)` what about this

Answer (score 0):

There are two models for product, first one is `product.template` which is the template for product and second one is `product.product` which inherits all data structure of `product.template` and this type of inheritance called `delegation inheritance`.

One of the reasons to use two models for product is using `product variants`, You will find one product template but many product variants for same product template which stored in `product.product`

The pos module extends `product.template` and adds `available_in_pos` field so this field will be available in `product.product` model because of the `delegation inheritance`.

So, you filter only products available in pos by using this domain `[('available_in_pos', '=', True)]`

**Examples:**

1. If you are using domain with `product_id` field which belong to
   `product.template` model, you can filter only products available
   in pos with the following domain `[('available_in_pos', '=', True)]`:

```
product_template = self.env['product.template'].search([('available_in_pos', '=', True)])
```

2. If you are using domain with `product_id` field which belong to
   `product.product` model, you can filter all products (include
   products variants) with following domain `[('available_in_pos', '=', True)]` or you can filter it using their product template uing this domain `[('product_tmpl_id.available_in_pos', '=', True)]`

```
product = self.env['product.product'].search([('available_in_pos', '=', True)])
```

or

```
product = self.env['product.product'].search([('product_tmpl_id.available_in_pos', '=', True)])
```